# OpenIdRelyingParty response is always Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to get OpenId login operational in an ASPX web application and I have no idea what is wrong.

First here is a version which works, but I can't use it, because Yadis fails to validate the relying party due to redirection, which leads to a warning like "Are you sure you want to send the data to suspicious client?" by the openID server.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        OpenIdRelyingParty openId = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

        IAuthenticationResponse response = openId.GetResponse();
        ValidateLogin(response);

        if (response == null || response.Status != AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated)
        {
            logger.Info("Not logged in.");
            Login(openId); //<-- this is why yadis discovery fails. When parsing the the page finding <meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="https://testServer.domain.cz/openidtrial/Content/yadis.xml" />
        }

    }
}

void DoTry(string identifier, Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        logger.ErrorException("Error getting response " + identifier, exception);
    }
}

void Login(OpenIdRelyingParty openId)
{
    var request = openId.CreateRequest(Identifier.Parse("https://openId.server.address"));
    request.AddExtension(new ClaimsRequest()
    {
        Nickname = DemandLevel.Request
    });

    logger.Info("sending request");
    request.RedirectToProvider();
}

void ValidateLogin(IAuthenticationResponse response)
{
    logger.Info(string.Format("response is null: {0}", response == null));
    if (response != null)
    {
        logger.Info(string.Format("response status is: {0}", response.Status));
    }
    if (response != null && response.Status == AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated)
    {
        logger.Info("authorization request received");
        logger.Info("ClaimedIdentifier " + response.ClaimedIdentifier);

        //var claimUntrusted = response.GetUntrustedExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
        var claim = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
        //logger.Info(string.Format("claimUntrusted is {0}", claimUntrusted != null ? "value" : "null"));
        logger.Info(string.Format("claim is {0}", claim != null ? "value" : "null"));
        DoTry("claim", () => logger.Info("claim nick " + claim.Nickname));
        //DoTry("claim untrusted", () => logger.Info("untrusted claim nick " + claimUntrusted.Nickname));
    }
}
```

Here is the content of log file:

```
Info|12:19:06,198|38-|Message:response is null: True| <--start up
Info|12:19:06,214|38-|Message:Not logged in.|
Info|12:19:07,602|38-|Message:sending request| <--auto redirection
Info|12:19:14,248|18-|Message:response is null: True| <-- Yadis discovery
Info|12:19:14,248|18-|Message:Not logged in.|
Info|12:19:14,497|18-|Message:sending request|
Info|12:19:16,853|38-|Message:response is null: True|
Info|12:19:16,853|38-|Message:Not logged in.|
Info|12:19:17,134|38-|Message:sending request|
Info|12:19:17,633|21-|Message:response is null: False|
Info|12:19:17,633|21-|Message:response status is: Failed|
Info|12:19:17,633|21-|Message:Not logged in.|
Info|12:19:17,898|21-|Message:sending request|
Info|12:19:18,085|38-|Message:response is null: True|
Info|12:19:18,085|38-|Message:Not logged in.|
Info|12:19:18,335|38-|Message:sending request|
Info|12:19:19,910|18-|Message:response is null: True|
Info|12:19:19,910|18-|Message:Not logged in.|
Info|12:19:20,176|18-|Message:sending request|
Info|12:19:20,909|38-|Message:response is null: False| <-- successful login
Info|12:19:20,909|38-|Message:response status is: Authenticated|
Info|12:19:20,909|38-|Message:authorization request received|
Info|12:19:20,909|38-|Message:ClaimedIdentifier ***identifier***|
Info|12:19:20,909|38-|Message:claim is value|
Info|12:19:20,909|38-|Message:claim nick testnick|
```

I tried to solve the redirection problem by removing the automatic rediction. I added a button which will do the the redirection manually. The altered parts of code follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //logger.Info(string.Format("request Path: {0}", Request.Url.AbsolutePath));
    //logger.Info(string.Format("Host name: {0}, Host IP: {1}", Request.UserHostName, Request.UserHostAddress));
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        OpenIdRelyingParty openId = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

        IAuthenticationResponse response = openId.GetResponse();
        ValidateLogin(response);

        if (response == null || response.Status != AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated)
        {
            logger.Info("Not logged in.");
            //Login(openId);
        }

    }
}

protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenIdRelyingParty openId = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
    Login(openId);
}
```

But when using this, the response.Status is *always* `AuthenticationStatus.Failed` after the authentification

Here is the content of the log file:

```
Info|12:14:41,481|36-|Message:response is null: True| <--start up
Info|12:14:41,497|36-|Message:Not logged in.|
Info|12:14:55,490|18-|Message:sending request| <--login button clicked
Info|12:15:01,543|18-|Message:response is null: True| <-- yadis discovery
Info|12:15:01,543|18-|Message:Not logged in.|
Info|12:15:03,540|28-|Message:response is null: True|
Info|12:15:03,540|28-|Message:Not logged in.|
Info|12:15:03,633|21-|Message:response is null: False| <-- response received
Info|12:15:03,633|21-|Message:response status is: Failed|
Info|12:15:03,633|21-|Message:Not logged in.|
```

I also tried to use `static OpenIdRelyingParty openId` instead of creating new instance in the methods. - doesn't help

Also I have tried to store the openId in a session like this - doesn't help:

```
OpenIdRelyingParty OpenId
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["openIdSession"] == null)
        {
            logger.Info("Creating OpenId");
            HttpContext.Current.Session["openIdSession"] = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        }
        return (OpenIdRelyingParty)HttpContext.Current.Session["openIdSession"];
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.
I took a original code from the post above (the first one, which was operational but not "user-friendly" because the yadis discovery failed and I added an explicit XRDS request handling.
It would probably be better to add an ashx handler to deal with the yadis, but this works too.

Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //XRDS request handling that solves the yadis discovery problem
    if (Request.AcceptTypes.Any(a => a.Contains("xrds")))
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/xrds+xml";
        string path = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath + "/Content/yadis.xml");
        logger.Info(string.Format("yadis path: {0}", path));
        Response.WriteFile(path);
        Response.End();
        return;
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        OpenIdRelyingParty openId = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

        IAuthenticationResponse response = openId.GetResponse();
        ValidateLogin(response);

        if (response == null || response.Status != AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated)
        {
            logger.Info("Not logged in.");
            Login(openId); //<-- this is why yadis discovery failed.
        }

    }
}
```